# How to trigger Azure Datafactory-v2 via rest api?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure and Azure Data Factory. I have built a pipeline in Azure Data Factory and now I am trying to trigger the pipeline via rest API from javascript but I am not able to find any concrete solution. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, you already have created pipeline in your adf account.You could use Azure Data Factory [Pipelines - Create Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createrun) REST api to execute it.

Before this process, you need to generate Authorization token in Headers. You could refer to [ADAL nodejs sdk](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs#server-to-server-via-client-credentials) to generate token. If you don't know what are these parameters:

[image]

,then please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and this [blog](https://arjunphp.com/how-to-execute-azure-rest-apis-node-js/) to get concepts of them.
And please note that you also need to grant ADFpermission to your ad app.

[image]

[image]

Finally,you could call the [Pipelines - Create Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createrun) REST api and provide auth token in the `header`.

Comment: Is there an easier approach to create this Authorization Token when you just need to use it in Postman?